# Intermittently get blank screen when opening code file

Tags: visual-studio-2017

Sometimes in Visual Studio 2017, when opening a code-behind file, the page is empty.

If I close all the tabs, and reopen the same file from the Solution Explorer, the code will display.

Is there something about the way the project file is being saved, when tabs are left open, that might be causing this blank screen? Is there a way to close all tabs automatically when VS is about to shut down? Or a way to tell VS not to even bother to remember which files were open?